# How to create custom methods using Struts2 REST plugin

Tags: java, rest, struts2, model-driven, struts2-rest-plugin

My problem concerns the creation of a custom method within an action. I'm using Struts2 and REST Plugin in order to implement a RESTful WebService. My action class is the following:

```
public class SampleController implements ModelDriven<Object> {

private Sample sample = new Sample();
private Collection<Sample> list;
private int id;

public HttpHeaders create() {
    sdao.save(sample);
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("create");
}   


public HttpHeaders destroy() {
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("destroy");
}

public HttpHeaders show() {
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("show").disableCaching();
}

public HttpHeaders update() {
    sdao.save(sample);
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("update");
}

public HttpHeaders index() {
    list = sdao.findAll();
    return new DefaultHttpHeaders("index").disableCaching();
}

public Object getModel() {
    return (list != null ? list : sample);
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    if (id != null) {
        this.sample = (Sample) sdao.findById(id);
    }
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

I can access to a resource via a `GET` HTTP method correctly. In order to use a custom method, called by passing a parameter to search resources i.e

```
public searchBySenderName(String senderName) {
    list.addAll(sdao.findBySenderName(senderName))
}
```

What is the correct procedures? How can I call it via `GET` following URL?

Answer (score -1):

You can call custom method from any of the predefined methods for `GET` (`index`, `show`) in your case, see [RESTful URL mapping logic](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/#restful-url-mapping-logic) .

> **RESTful URL Mapping Logic**
>
> This Restful action mapper enforces Ruby-On-Rails REST-style mappings.
> If the method is not specified (via '!' or 'method:' prefix), the
> method is "guessed" at using REST-style conventions that examine the
> URL and the HTTP method. Special care has been given to ensure this
> mapper works correctly with the codebehind plugin so that XML
> configuration is unnecessary.

---

Of course you can change the method names used by the action mapper, but it will affect a whole application. If you already occupied a resource URL then you should use another to perform its job. This is in case if you are using a strict `rest` mapper. In the [mixed mode](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/rest/#rest-and-non-restful-urls-together-configuration) you can map an usual action to some action method.

> **REST and non-RESTful URL's Together Configuration**
>
> If you want to keep using some non-RESTful URL's alongside your REST
> stuff, then you'll have to provide for a configuration that utilizes
> to mappers.
>
> Plugins contain their own configuration. If you look in the Rest
> plugin jar, you'll see the `struts-plugin.xml` and in that you'll see
> some configuration settings made by the plugin. Often, the plugin just
> sets things the way it wants them. You may frequently need to override
> those settings in your own `struts.xml`.

---

And last, you mightn't specify a method via `!` or `method:` prefix because it's restricted by default configuration.

Comment: Thank you very kind. But how can I invoke my custom method? I don't find the right URL path :-(

Comment: You don't need it, the URL is defined by convention, but you need a controller.

Comment: Thank you again. This remains a mystery to me. I implemented a method such this:   
public String test() {
list = sdao.findBySenderName("raspberrypi-0");
return "test";
}

But i can view the result by passing by an id resource (i.e. MyProject/sample/24/test.xml)

can I have a clear example?

Comment: Sure, [download](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts2316-SNAPSHOT) the struts2 Example Applications and check out the struts2-rest-showcase application, a complete WAR file, that demonstrates a simple REST web program.