# Add REST to existing struts 2 non-REST application

Tags: java, rest, struts2

I have a working java application based on struts. I need to make a mobile version for it. and I will expose it using RESTful web services.

I've done some researches and found out about REST Plugin for struts 2 , but it means that i will have to re write all my exisiting actions in order to transfer them to REST Controllers.

Is there a way to use my exisiting struts 2 actions code? (maybe adding some annotations or so) or do I have to rewrite the REST controllers from scratch ?

Comment: Restful mapping is different, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26703495/573032

Comment: Thank you very much Roman, Still the idea is not quit clear for me, since the question you listed is not really my case.
Could you please give me a way to go ?

Comment: Are you trying to add rest endpoints to an existing Struts 2 application?  Another option is to drop in a jax-rs implementation, such as, Jersey alongside struts.

Comment: Thank you @PaulZepernick, what's the use case of each one ? Jersey or Strut plugin ? how do I know which one suite the best for my case?

Comment: @Faouzy I listed the answer, and it exactly concerns to your case where you want to use restful api along with non-restful actions. If you need more links, i can give you more. If you want me to answer your question then you should rewrite it to be more clear to understand your case and has richer quality contents.